# What does %defattr mean in RPM spec files?

Tags: permissions, rpm, rpm-spec

While creating RPMs, the RPM spec files have a directive `%defattr` . I know that it defines the default attributes for the files that are installed by that RPM. If I write the `%defattr` as below, what does it mean?

```
%defattr(-testuser, testuser)
```

Answer (score 34):

The mode you specified is invalid. %defattr takes four arguments

From http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-FLIST-DEFATTR-DIRECTIVE

> The %defattr Directive
>
> The %defattr directive allows setting of default attributes for files and directives. The %defattr has a similar format to the %attr directive:
>
> 1. The default permissions, or "mode" for files.
> 2. The default user id.
> 3. The default group id.
> 4. The default permissions, or "mode" for directories.
>
> The %attr directive has the following format:
>
> %defattr(file mode, user, group, dir mode)
>
> As with %attr if a particular attribute does not need to
>   be specified (usually because the file is installed with that
>   attribute set properly), then that attribute may be replaced with a
>   dash. In addition the directory mode may be ommited. %defattr tends to
>   be used at the top of %files.

Comment: Nice explanation. A valid example I see often in spec files is `%defattr(-,root,root)`.

Answer (score 8):

To set permissions and ownerships in a spec file treat the directory like a file thusly...
%defattr will set all files without %attr (in this case rww owner apache group apache and set directories to 755).

```
%files
#%attr(<mode>, <user>, <group>) file
%defattr(644,apache,apache,755)
%attr(-,apache,apache) /var/www/coolapp
%attr(-,apache,apache) /var/www/coolapp/js
%attr(-,apache,apache) /var/www/coolapp/static
/var/www/coolapp/index.html
/var/www/coolapp/__init__.py
/var/www/coolapp/settings.py
/var/www/coolapp/urls.py
/var/www/coolapp/wsgi.py
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was asking what the `-` means in the first field, which is answered by brightlancer's quotation of Maximum RPM.